# How to close all instance of Provider.family when dispose screen widget flutter_riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, video-player

I'm creating a scroll multiple video screen. I'm using [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) and creating multiple BetterPlayerControllers when a video plays and cache it with Provider.family.

My code in screen (I commented for each function I used):

```
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/src/pages/social_video/services/services.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/utils/vill_dimensions.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'models/models.dart';
import 'widgets/widgets.dart';

/// List video include url. I will get from API
final dataSourceProvider = StateProvider<List<PostM>>((ref) => []);

/// Control current video is playing.
final currentPageSProvider = StateProvider<int>(
  (ref) => 0,
);

/// List video active (when scroll to a video, i will add to currentPageSProvider)
final activePageSProvider = StateProvider<List<int>>(
  (ref) {
    return [];
  },
);

/// To create multiple BetterPlayerDataSource for each video_id
final dataSourceByPageProvider = Provider.family<BetterPlayerDataSource, int>(
  (ref, index) {
    final videos = ref.watch(dataSourceProvider);
    String source = videos[index].video!.playUrl!;

    BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
      source,
      liveStream: true,
      videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.hls,
      cacheConfiguration: const BetterPlayerCacheConfiguration(
        useCache: false,
      ),
    );

    ref.onDispose(() {
      //  clear garbage
      debugPrint('dataSourceByPageProvider clear garbage');
    });
    return dataSource;
  },
);

/// To create multiple BetterPlayerController for each video_id
final playerControllerByPageProvider = Provider.family<BetterPlayerController, int>(
  (ref, id) {
    final source = ref.watch(dataSourceByPageProvider(id));
    final controller = BetterPlayerController(
      const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        // aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        looping: true,
        showPlaceholderUntilPlay: false,
        showSubtitlesDrawer: false,
        autoDetectFullscreenAspectRatio: true,
        placeholder: SizedBox.shrink(),
        autoPlay: false,
        autoDispose: false,
        handleLifecycle: false,
        controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
          showControls: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          loadingWidget: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
      ),
      betterPlayerDataSource: source,
    );

    ref.onDispose(() {
      //  clear garbage
      //??? It's run after I join this screen. Not when I leave this screen.
      debugPrint('playerControllerByPageProvider clear garbage');
      controller.clearCache();
      controller.dispose();
    });

    return controller;
  },
);

/// To create multiple plau, pause status for each video_id
final playPauseProvider = Provider.family<bool, PlayPauseProviderParamsClass>(
  (ref, params) {
    final player = ref.watch(
      playerControllerByPageProvider(params.index),
    );

    if (params.isPlay) {
      if (player.isPlaying() ?? false) return false;

      player.play().then(
        (value) {
          ref.read(activePageSProvider.notifier).update(
                (state) => [params.index, ...state],
              );
        },
      );

      return true;
    } else {
      if (!(player.isPlaying() ?? false)) return false;

      player.pause().then(
        (value) async {
          ref.read(activePageSProvider.notifier).update(
            (state) {
              state.remove(params.index);
              return [...state];
            },
          );
          if (!(player.isVideoInitialized() ?? false)) return false;
          if (player.videoPlayerController?.value.duration == null) {
            return false;
          }
          if ((player.videoPlayerController?.value.duration?.compareTo(Duration.zero) ?? 0) > 0) return false;
          await player.seekTo(Duration.zero);
        },
      );
    }
    return false;
  },
);

class SocialVideoScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SocialVideoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<SocialVideoScreen> createState() => _MyHomePageV3State();
}

class _MyHomePageV3State extends ConsumerState<SocialVideoScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((final _) => _init());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    debugPrint('SocialVideoScreen dispose');
  }

  _init() async {
    /// get list video from apis
    await _getListPosts();
    
    /// play the first video
    ref.read(playPauseProvider(
      const PlayPauseProviderParamsClass(index: 0, isPlay: true),
    ));    
  }

  Future<void> _getListPosts() async {
    final data = await SocialVideoService.instance.getListPosts();
    final list = data.map((e) => e).toList();
    ref.read(dataSourceProvider.notifier).state = list;
  }

  /// Listion scroll event
  bool _onNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification.depth != 0) return false;
    if (notification is! ScrollUpdateNotification) return false;

    final metrics = notification.metrics as PageMetrics;
    final page = metrics.page!.round();
    // debugPrint('ScrollEndNotification: ${metrics.page} $page');

    if (page == ref.read(currentPageSProvider)) return false;

    ref.read(currentPageSProvider.notifier).state = page;
    _pauseAllAndPlayIndex(page);

    return false;
  }

  _pauseAllAndPlayIndex(int index) {
    final listActive = ref.read(activePageSProvider);
    for (var activeItem in listActive) {
      ref.read(
        playPauseProvider(
          PlayPauseProviderParamsClass(index: activeItem, isPlay: false),
        ),
      );
      ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(activeItem)).pause();
    }
    if (index >= 2) {
      ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(index - 2)).dispose();
      ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(index + 2)).dispose();
      // ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(index + 2)).clearCache();
    }
    // ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(index + 1)).preCache(
    //       ref.read(dataSourceByPageProvider(index + 1)),
    //     );

    ref.read(
      playPauseProvider(
        PlayPauseProviderParamsClass(index: index, isPlay: true),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final videos = ref.watch(dataSourceProvider);
    debugPrint('SocialVideoScreen build ${videos.length}');

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: _onNotification,
              child: PageView.builder(
                allowImplicitScrolling: true,
                itemCount: videos.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  PostM post = videos[index];
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      _VideoPlayer(
                        key: ValueKey('_VideoPlayer_$index'),
                        index: index,
                      ),
                      const TopShadowW(),
                      const BottomShadowW(),
                      // _DebugPlayerWidget(post: post),
                      const BackButtonW(),
                      PostLayoutW(post: post),
                      Positioned(
                          top: 120,
                          bottom: VillDimensions.padBottomScreen,
                          right: Get.width * 1 / 5,
                          left: 0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              ref.read(
                                playPauseProvider(
                                  PlayPauseProviderParamsClass(index: index, isPlay: false),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _VideoPlayer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const _VideoPlayer({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
  });

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return BetterPlayer(
      key: ValueKey('_BetterPlayer_$index'),
      controller: ref.watch(playerControllerByPageProvider(index)),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem: When i scroll multiple video => i create multiple instance of playerControllerByPageProvider to control BetterPlayerController. But when I leave this screen and dispose instance for each BetterPlayerController, it's not close, ANd it keep when I join this screen again.

my dispose controller code:

```
ref.read(activePageSProvider.notifier).state.forEach((element) {
            ref.read(
              playPauseProvider(
                PlayPauseProviderParamsClass(index: element, isPlay: false),
              ),
            );
            ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(element)).pause();
            ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(element)).clearCache();
            ref.read(playerControllerByPageProvider(element)).dispose();
          });

          ref.read(activePageSProvider.notifier).state.clear();
```